# Put ordered list in a table row <tr>. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have here a sample code of putting an ordered list (1,2,3 ...):

This is my JScipt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul").each(function() {
     $(this).find("li").each(function(count) {
        $(this)
          .css("list-style-type", "none")
          .prepend("<div class='listnumber'>" + (count + 1) + ".</div>");
     });
  });
  })    
</script>
```

For the HTML, simple as this:

```
<ul>
  <li>CSS</li>
  <li>CSS3</li>
  <li>PHP</li>
  <li>CakePHP</li>
 </ul>
```

For CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .listnumber
 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
 }
</style>
```

Using: 1.9.1.js and this perfectly works. What I want is how to number all the data inside a table. Or how to put the tags `<ul><li></li></ul>` inside `<tr><td></td></tr>`

I have tried:

```
<ul> 
    <li>
      <tr>
        <td>
          CSS
        </td>
      </tr>
   </li>

   <li>
      <tr>
        <td>
          CSS3
        </td>
      </tr>
   </li>

   <li>
      <tr>
        <td>
          PHP
        </td>
      </tr>
   </li>

   <li>
      <tr>
        <td>
          CakePHP
        </td>
      </tr>
   </li>

  </ul>
```

But the numbering did not work. Why is that? Letting me understand is another learning for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't do that.... why can't just add a td with the numbers

Comment: @Arun P Johny: what if im looping the tds?

Comment: Try [this tool](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) with the "Document fragment" option. You'll see that *document type does not allow element "TR" here*.

Comment: Instead of <li><tr><td> you could try <li><TABLE><tr><td> and check it. "<table><tr><td>" and their closing tabs are the minimum code for a table.

Comment: @Minister: Oh, gosh. I'm sorry, what I've run was the old file. I've tried transferring the `<li>` outside `<table>` but doesn't really work. Shame on me. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr><td class="nr"></td><td>This</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="nr"></td><td>should</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="nr"></td><td>work...</td></tr>   
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("nr");
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].innerHTML = (i+1)+".";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my belated solution:

```
    <ol style="list-style: decimal inside;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right; display: list-item;"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ol>
```

The list can be modified with the CSS "list-style", "text-align" and "display" attributes. The beauty of this method is that it is pure HTML and CSS, no javascript or jQuery required, and for ordered lists the list numbers are automatically updated when a row is removed from the table. And it works in Chrome and its variants and Firefox. Don't know about IE.

Comment: It is wise to set `ol`'s padding and margin to zero, so it does not add space around the table

Answer (score 1):

I've streamlined my method with the following CSS and HTML:

```
/* Use this class for the first list element */
.list-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #e7fe9d;
    border: 1px solid #dde06e;
}

.list-header, .list-header-plain {
    counter-reset: castcounter;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Use this for each list element digit */
.list-ordinal {
    padding: 0 .5%;
    width: 6%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.list-ordinal, .list-ordinal-plain {
    text-align: right;
}

.list-ordinal::before, .list-ordinal-plain::before {
    counter-increment: castcounter;
    content: counter(castcounter);
}

.list-ordinal::after, .list-ordinal-plain::after {
    content: ".";
}

<table class="list-header">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <div class="list-ordinal"></div>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

list-haeder-plain and list-ordinal-plain are minimum requirements for working table counters. Use the non-plain variants for additional visuals but are entirely optional.

Again, this method works in firefox and chrome variants.